# Why is my app detected as a Virus? It happens after updating of SDK Version and Adsense

Tags: android

My App have decent downloads, and recently I updated my app with the following

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 28
```

And Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0' 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

And Manifest file added these new entries:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-16728770xxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"/>
```

Now After this upgrade Phone Manager showing my application is a virus:

**Risk details:** This Virus is a Trojan. It can cause devices to be accessed by remote applications without authorization.

These are the only permissions my app is using (network only for adsense/admob)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

any one face such issue after recent updates?

why suddenly my app is detected as a Virus?

Comment: What kind of Phone manager is that? Usually, the 'viruses' that most 'anti-viruses' throw read an app's permission list and from there they categorize whether an app is a virus/PUP/malware. They may be categorizing the app as a virus due to the 'risky' permissions according to them.

Comment: Same problem with Avast antivirus : I am using NDK from day one to encrypt , for reference i am adding here my app id com.istudentworld.clatpreviouspapers

Comment: My issue is resolved after updated NDK fully to CPP instead of C not sure what is the exact issue.